# Saving javascript to generate value in Database - better solution?

Tags: mysql, database

Hi I am having an issue with deciding how to store/calculate a value. The value is this case is dynamically generated by executing a javascript function that is stored in a mysql database.

The company I work for originally did this because other values that are used by the stored javascript function can be changed and because this is done by a AJAX request, the value needs to be calculated on the clients side. Somehow this doesn't feel right, and I think there has to be a better way to store this.

Now I am not sure how I should solve this, but I hope some of you can point me in the right direction.

I hope I explained the problem clear enough.

EDIT: An example.
There is a value x that needs to be calculated and currently this happens.

```
function example(){
    if(y == true){
       return 0;
    }
    var result = z / areaM2;
    if(result > 100){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 2;
    }
}
x = example();
```

y, z and areaM2 are actual stored variables.

Answer (score 1):

You should only save the values that can change, not the function itself, even if it could change. In the latter case you'd need to provide multiple functions in a JavaScript file and have a property stored in your DB to define which function to use.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along with me. But with this solution it is still not possible to export the data to another non-javascript format (XML or EXCEL) is there a way to tell PHP to calculate a value? And preferable not by hard-coding all the if-statements that determin a calculated value.

Comment: Can the calculation function change?

Comment: No, it is made only once. But for each case there is a different function.

Comment: What do you mean with for each case?

Comment: There are multiple variables that need to be calculated. All by their own function. I meant one variable: one case. sorry for the confusion.